# Prove the existence of a bijection from an input region to a output region.

Tags: functions

I will start with an example.

Consider the function $y = |x|$. 
This function identifies a set of disjoint input regions $A = \{r_1, r_2, \dots\}$, in which every region is a subset of $\mathbb R$, onto an output region $B$, subset of $\mathbb R$ as well, if for all the input regions there exists a bijection from from $r_i$ to $B$.

For example for a output region $(0, 1)$ we have two input regions $(-1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$.

Now the real question:

let $x, b$ belong to $\mathbb R^d$, $W$ belong yo $\mathbb R^{d\times d}$, such that

$W_{ij} = 2$ if $i = j$ and $0$ if $i$ is different from $j$. $b_i = -1$

consider the function $f(x) = |Wx + b|$ applied element-wise

Find the input regions identified onto $(0,1)^d$ by $f$ and prove there exists a bijection.